# Howto delete milestones using REST API in Gitlab ?

Tags: rest, gitlab, milestone

I could not find any talk about this feature in [Gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/milestones.html)

I tried to do it, but got a 405 error code.

Is anybody knows how to do that ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if it's not listed there, you can't remove it with API. But you can close the milestone with

```
PUT /projects/:id/milestones/:milestone_id
```

passing `state_event` as `close`.